# Linking multiple model relationships with views in django

Tags: django

I have a project with a custom user model, users can login and create a company, this all works fine. Now I want everything else in the project linked to the company they created, ie leads for that company. THe first layer linking the user to the company works great, but now combining the third layer seems to be not working. Here is the code and then what I want it to do follows.

**The link from my template**

```
<li><a href="{% url 'nodiso:leadlist' pk=company.id %}">Sales</a></li>
```

**The URl**

```
url(r'^leads/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.LeadListView.as_view(), name='leadlist'),
```

**The View**

```
class LeadListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    login_url = '/scrty/login/'
    template_name = "nodiso/leadslist.html"
    model = models.Leads
    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Leads.objects.filter(company=self.pk)
```

**The Model**

```
class Leads(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=265)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=265)
    tel = models.IntegerField()
    dateenq = models.DateField()
```

So basically I am trying the create a list view for leads, but it should only be the leads linked to the company, I also would like to somehow display information regarding the company in the views for leads. Basically linking but also combining bot the views with each other.

Not sure if my approach is correct at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by storing values in a session

```
def comp_select(request, company_id):
    comp = models.Company.objects.get(id=company_id)
    request.session['company'] = comp.name
    request.session['compid'] = company_id
    return redirect('nodisoapp:working',company_id)
```